# Error Coming when passing props from one component to another and vice - versa in react using typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

In react, when I pass information from App component to App2 component as

```
<App2 value = {this.state.name}/>
```

it works well, but when I try to pass information from App2 component to App1 component as

```
<App1 value = {this.state.name2}/>
```

inside the render function of App2 component , it gives an error :-

```
[ts] 'render' implicitly has return type 'any' because it does not have a return type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in one of its return expressions.
```

The code for App1 component is :-

```
import * as React from "react";
 import App2 from './App2';

interface IState{
    name   : string,
    age    : 5;
}

interface Iprops{
    value ? : any
}
class App extends React.Component<Iprops,IState>{
    constructor(props:any)
    {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            age  : 5,
            name : ""   
        }
        this.change = this.change.bind(this);
    }   

    public change(event : any){
        // alert("you have submitted the form");
        this.setState({
            name : event.target.value
        });
    }
    public render()
    {
        return(
            <div>
               <input type="text" value = {this.state.name} onChange = {this.change}/>
               <App2 value = {this.state.name}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

and App2 component code is :-

```
import * as React from "react";
import App from './App'
interface Iprops{
    value ? : any;
}
interface Istate{
    name2 : string
}
class App2 extends React.Component<Iprops,Istate>{
    constructor(props:any)
    {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            name2 : " "
        }

    }

    public change(event : any){
        this.setState({name2 : event.target.value})
    }

    public render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <h4>
              <input type="text" value = {this.props.value} onChange = {this.change}/>
              Hello, I am in App3 component.
              <App value = {this.state.name2}/>
          </h4>
        </div>
      )
    }
}

export default App2;
```

Is there any other method to pass the information vice-versa between components in react using typescript.

Comment: So what does render look like?..

Comment: impossible to answer without seeing the code of your components, however the error seems to be pretty self-explanatory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note, that you have circular dependency between `App` and `App2`. Typescript is unable to infer return type of `App2#render` as it uses `App` in it's return expression which in turn uses `App2` which isn't yet fully defined ...

Long story short - declare your render methods as follows:

```
public render(): JSX.Element {
    // ...
}
```

Thanks to this Typescript compiler knows `render` signature without looking at function contents.